# Magento 2 Add custom class before "main.content" excluding Home Page

Tags: magento2, default.xml

I am looking for a solution to add a custom class before "main.content" for all pages remaining home page. Currently, I am doing below code

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
           <container name="your.custom.name" as="your-custom" label="Your Label Name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_class" htmlId="your-id" before="page-footer"/>
  </referenceContainer>
  <move element="main.content" destination="your.custom.name"/>
```

in default.xml.

but this code adding "custom_class" class for all pages. I want to exclude from the home page. Please suggest if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `your.custom.name` container from the `cms_index_index.xml` file placed under `Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml` with below content.

```
<referenceContainer name="your.custom.name" remove="1" />
```

**Edit:**

Add below content in `Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml` file.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
       <container name="your.custom.name" as="your-custom" htmlTag="div" before="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="main.content" destination="your.custom.name"/>
```

**Hope this helps!!!**

Comment: @summit,It is working but this is removing all div under custom class including "main.content" so home page totally distruct.I want remove only class name not totally div.

Comment: Add <move element="main.content" destination="page.wrapper"/> in cms_index_index.xml file.

Comment: @summit,I have tried but still not got any success,I just want to add class for all page before main.content and remove it for cms page.so if you have any other idea please share me.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can remove the class and id from the custom container with my updated code. Also, you can add your own custom class which is only used on the home page. For example: htmlClass="test" in the container tag.

Please review.

Comment: @summit,but I dont require to add class on home page,I just want to all page and excluding from home page.

Comment: I can understand your query, but after Magento 2.2 + the removing class from the container, the feature is removed by Magento. You can override the custom class of the added custom container for the home page.

Comment: @summit,Working perfectly its overriding default.xml class with dummy class.